# Is the natural neighbor an exact interpolator in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, interpolation

Is the natural neighbor ( or even nearest neighbor) considered an exact interpolator? I believe splining or kriging could be considered exact... but what about the natural or nearest neighbor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An interpolator is considered exact if it returns the value of an observation when you are exactly at the same location (if your interpolation output is a raster, then the center of the pixel must be exactly at the same location than the observed values). With this definition in mind :

Natural neighbors, nearest neighbor, inverse distance weigth and TIN are exact interpolators.

Simple kriging is an exact interpolator if the nugget is zero.

Spline is an exact interpolator, but I think that the regularized spline is not.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that ordinary kriging is inexact when there is a nugget (which there should most certainly be). Folks often call it exact but ignore the error. There are numerous spline methods. In its very essence, splines are exact however once parameters are applied many are not. A case in point is TPS where, in the additive model, as phi increases surface tension but the observations adhere to their original distribution which is the cause of the overshoot problem. However, in spline regularization as tau increases the surface can be smoothed away from the observations.